# Xml serialization/deserealization and html character encoding

Tags: .net, serialization, xmlserializer

I am doing serialization of xml into objects and visa versa using the .NET XmlSerializer. The xml contains encoded special characters, such as greater then and/or less then symbols. When the xml is serialized into objects, I need those greater/less then symbols to be be actually converted to "<" or ">" and when going from object to xml, I need the actual "<" or ">" to be converted into their encoded versions.

I have a couple of work around/hacks in the UI which do the conversion, but  I am looking for a better way to handle this. I was hoping there would be some parameter setting in the actual serializer that would do this when I serialize/deserealize. I looked around and played with various writers/steams that get passed to the serializer, but could not find anything.

Anyone know what is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

`XmlSerializer` should be doing exactly that by default. If it's not, can you post some details?

When you serialize an object into XML, string values like `<` and `>` are automatically escaped - converted into `&lt;` and `&gt;` because those characters are used in tags so they can't appear in elements.

When you deserialize the XML back into an object it does the opposite, putting back the `<` and `>`.  Take a look at this console app and the output:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass {Value = "<div>I am HTML!</div>"};
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (MyClass));
        var xmlString = new StringBuilder();
        using (var writer = new StringWriter(xmlString))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, myClass);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Serialized:");
        Console.WriteLine(xmlString.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlString.ToString()))
        {
            var deserializedClass = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as MyClass;
            Console.WriteLine("Deserialized myClass.Value: " + deserializedClass.Value);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

`Serialized:`
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`
`<MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Value>&lt;div&gt;I am HTML!&lt;/div&gt;</Value>`

`Deserialized myClass.Value: <div>I am HTML!</div>`